# When using Spring Cloud Contracts, why is the producer creating the contracts?

Tags: spring-cloud, consumer, spring-cloud-contract

I have been playing with Spring Cloud Contracts. Here is my understanding of the workflow thus far.

On the server Side

- Write the contract (in groovy or yaml)
- Auto generate the tests (using gradle plugin)
- Setup BaseClass that does appropriate setup setups for the Controller
- Run the auto generated Tests
- Publish the stubs jar file that is generated to some local repo (which contains wiremock server built in, with request/responses)

On the client side

- Download the stub jar file
- Write tests against this stub jar. Use stubrunner to verify responses

What I fail to understand is how is this Consumer driven? The contracts seems to originate from the producer, the consumer seems to be passively testing what the producer has published (using stubs jar file). A producer could accidentally not update the contracts, but make breaking changes. This can lead to tests on the client passing even though it should have failed. Is this true or have I misunderstood a step where the contracts are created from the consumer side

Thoughts?

Comment: What you're describing is producer, not consumer, driven. If the producer makes breaking changes and the contract isn't updated, it will fail the verification.

Comment: My confusion is around the workflow, in all the examples I have seen, the producer generates the contract, the consumer is merely executing their tests against this jar file. If the tests fail on the consumer side, is the expectation that the consumer team talks to the producer team and conveys the failure? It doesn't seem to me as Consumer Driven.

Comment: Why *would* that seem consumer driven? It's not; as you say, the producer generates the contract and the producer is merely tested against it.

Comment: But isnt spring cloud contract supposed to promote **Consumer Driven Contract**  testing? One of the main advantages of CDC is to let the producers know via automated tests, when they are introducing breaking changes. Putting that responsibility on each consumer to ensure that they are compatible with the producer seems to be against CDC (very good chance, I could have gotten CDC wrong, in which case please do correct me)

Answer (score 1):

**Consumer Driven Contract** (CDC) Development is basically a **Test Driven Development** (TDD) extended to the Producer-Consumer applications. Since it's TDD - tests should come first and then the implementation. And since it's Consumer Driven - the *consumer creates tests for the producer*.

So let's assume that we a have a Producer and a Consumer and some new `feature` that needs to be implemented. In CDC the workflow would go as follows (you can find more information in the [official documentation](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract#consumer-side-loan-issuance)).

On the Consumer side:

- Write the missing implementation for the feature
- Clone **Producer** repository locally
- Define the contract locally in the repository of **Producer** (and auto-generate unit tests for it)
- Run the integration tests (on **cosumer's** side)
- File a pull request

On the Producer side:

- Take over the pull request (tests are already generated here by the **cosumer**)
- Write the missing implementation (TDD-style)
- Deploy your app
- Work online

It all makes sense now since **consumer** writes contracts for the new feature (but in the **producer's** repository) - we have a **Consumer Driven Approach**.

Comment: This makes sense to me, but in my mind is not a scalable approach. As a consumer of many services, I cannot possibly be expected to clone source code that belongs to another team, be able to build and add contract tests to it.  Feels like too much responsibility is put on the consumer side. Thoughts?

Comment: Well, every approach only makes sense in a certain situations - there is no "silver bullets". If you are evaluating CDC and see that it doesn't suite you that well - you should either adapt it more for your needs or check for another one.

Comment: You can also store contracts in an external repo where all contacts are stored.